# Zurb Foundation Reveal Modal on iOS

Tags: css, modal-dialog

I am using Zurb Foundation 6. My reveal modal works great on the desktop and looks good for mobile devices in Chrome Dev Tools. But once I try it on an actual device, the modal opens off screen. The user has to swipe up to get to the modal. The problem is the user may not know they have to swipe up to get it. Is there any way to make the modal open on top of the content on ios devices. Any assistance is appreciated!

I have tested on iphone 12 and the Chrome dev tools.

Here is the code I have implemented with the css used to try to keep the modal on top.

````
                    <h3>Comments, Priority & Position</h3>
                    <p class='small'>Add or edit comments, priority or positions.</p>
                    <form action='' method='post'>
                    <p>Form content goes here</p>
                    <button class='close-button' data-close aria-label='Close modal' type='button'>
                    <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <button type='submit' class='button tiny'>Save</button>
                    </form>
                    
                </div>"; ```

CSS

.reveal.full { top: 0 !important; }
````

Comment: Is this your full CSS code below? Could you please post your full modal markup and the all of your CSS? I don't know what Zurb adds as CSS for the modal, but if you say top: 0, your modal will be always on the top of the page in combination with e.g.: position fixed.

Comment: my css is too long to post here. I did notice going back in and testing that the full class on the modal did not work on mobile device. Removing the full class and the custom css allowed the modal to open but again, off screen.

Comment: Here is the code that opens the modal: ```<a class='button tiny' data-open='add-comment'><i class='far fa-pencil-alt'></i></a>```

Comment: Sorry, I mean all the modal relevant CSS, not everything. If you inspect the container with the classes .reveal.full, may there be a position fixed as well there?

Comment: @KurtLagerbier, thank you for your response. That was the only custom modal css. All else is using the Zurb Foundation 6 Reveal.

Comment: Thank you @KurtLagerbier for your help. I really appreciate your input. You got me thinking about where I needed to look.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have solved the issue. The problem was I had the button for opening the modal inside a dropdown callout. Moving the button outside of the dropdown callout seems to have fixed the problem. Slightly different look than I was going for but problem solved.